# Internet not working (local network works) after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade, internet

I have an internet connection that works through a proxy that requires username & password. After online upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04, I am unable to connect to internet, pinging to popular sites doesn't work. However, I am able to ping to local addresses in my office network. I shall post any more info if needed. I am a networking noob and didn't fiddle with anything in my network settings yet.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)to fix this issue.

```
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: Please give a more complete answer to the problem.